# jQuery.preventDefault(), jQuery.stopPropagation() e jquery.StopImmediatePropagation()... sem jQuery!

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Existe uma implementação *crossbrowser* para os métodos [jQuery.Event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [jQuery.Event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) e [jQuery.Event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) que não requeira a jQuery?

Tenho um recurso muito específico que não justificaria depender da jQuery, mesmo que por CDNs, os quais eu não confio.

Pelo código-fonte de [jQuery.Event](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L668) é possível ver que os três métodos são prototipados com base na sua disponibilidade no objeto [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Mas pela "documentação não-oficial" no MDN, [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) tem restrição de disponibilidade de browser (Internet Explorer 9).

[Nesse stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575273/cross-browser-preventdefault-without-jquery) do SOEN tem uma implementação ao que me pareceu suficientemente compatível para o [jQuery.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), mas e os outros?

A intenção não é **apenas** saber quais invenções "microsoftianas" equivalem a cada método do Evento e sim ter uma resposta definitiva sobre possíveis *fallbacks* (até mesmo por enriquecimento do KB do site) **e** quando ou em quais situações esses *fallbacks** deveria ou precisariam ser aplicados.

Answer (score 3):

`.stopPropagation` e `.preventDefault` são coisas diferentes.

**Impedir o comportamento "por defeito" (default):**

Quando eu preciso de bloquear uma ação do seu comportamento "default" em JavaScript puro uso `return false;`, isso funciona para todos os browsers.

O IE tem o [event.returnValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) que é uma invenção da Microsoft mas o `return false;` tem o mesmo efeito.

> Solução cross browser: `event.preventDefault(); event.returnValue = false;`

**Parar a propagação (bubling) do evento na árvore do DOM:**

O que o `return false;` não faz é parar a propagação do evento aí pode ser util usar:

`e.stopPropagation()` e `event.cancelBubble = true;`. O `.cancelBubble` é a versão da Microsoft do `stopPropagation` necessário nas versões antigas (IE<9).

> Solução cross browser: `e.stopPropagation(); event.cancelBubble = true;`

Answer (score 0):

Os métodos `event.preventDefault()` e `event.stopPropagation()` não estão presentes no Internet Explorer 8 ou versões inferiores. Se você quer deixar seu site com compatibilidade com essas versões, será necessário que você trate, no JavaScript, a existência de tais funções. Em relação ao `event.preventDefault()`, você pode utilizar o `event.returnValue`, e em relação ao `event.stopPropagation()`, você pode utilizar o `event.cancelBubble`. Não existem outras alternativas em outros navegadores populares, como o Firefox e o Chrome.

Comment: Apesar de não gostar de Javascript eu cheguei a essa conclusão mas, se apenas *event.stopPropagation()* precisa de uma implementação diferenciada para considerar também o *cancelBubble*, porquê no link do SOEN que eu citei é feito o mesmo tipo de *fallback* para o *event.preventDefault()*, retornando *false* caso este não esteja disponível no objeto?

Comment: De acordo com a [documentação da Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975460(v=vs.85).aspx), o `event.preventDefault()` é similar ao `event.returnValue` do Internet Explorer 8 e anteriores.

Comment: Eu acho que você não entendeu o objetivo da pergunta. Foi bom que você tenha se disponibilizado a trazer essas duas informações, muito embora a segunda já estivesse implícita na resposta do SOEN.