# Anular click do elemento pai jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como posso impedir que no click do #b ele execute o click do #link, gostaria que ele alertasse apenas "b"

```js
$("#link").on('click',function(){ alert('link') });

$("#b").on('click',function(){ alert('b') });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link">A<b id="b">b</b></a>
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42112/129

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta inserir um [`stopPropagation();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) após o `alert('b')`:

```js
$("#link").on('click',function(event){
  alert('link');
  
});

$("#b").on('click',function(event){
  alert('b');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link">A<b id="b">b</b></a>
```

Comment: Valeeeeu!! comandinho simples mas que salva muitas vidas rsrs